# C++ program quits after inputing double when int required. How to fix?

Tags: c++, validation, input, double, character

I have an assignment in which i have to make a program which takes the user input (natural number is required) and then prints out the reverse number. The program does that just fine however i also have to make sure that the program doesn't give me any errors when inputing values which aren't natural numbers. The program quits if i enter a double values or if i enter numbers followed by characters. In the rest of the cases the program works just fine. What could be causing these problems?

```
int number;
char x = 'c';
while (x == 'c') {
    cout << "Enter a number\n";
    cin >> number;
    while (!(cin.good()) || number < 1 || floor(number) != number) {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(256,'\n');
        cout << "Try again.\n";
        cin >> number;
    }
    string reverse;
    stringstream convert; 
    convert << number;
    reverse = convert.str();
    reverse = string (reverse.rbegin(),reverse.rend());
    cout << "The reverse number for number " << number << " is " << reverse << endl;
    cout << "If you want to continue using the program enter 'c',\nif you want to close the program enter anythin else\n";
    cin >> x;
    }
```

Comment: You can remove `floor(number) != number`, that will never be true for an `int`, regardless of what is input.

Comment: floor() gives you a double cast it to an Integer.

Comment: No, `floor` gives you a `double` that's been `floor`'d.  `(int)doubleValue` gives you a `double` cast to an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

It is because with let say **123.456** your program reads **123** as `int`. Then reverses it then expects `char x == 'c'` but gets dot **.**.

Read `std::string` from `std::cin` after that check if it is `int`.

```
std::string reverse;
std::cin >> reverse;

std::istringstream test(reverse);
int value; std::string rest;
if (!(test >> value) || (test >> rest)) // must read int but nothing more
{
  prompt for new value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would actually take `double` as the input type and then convert that to a natural number since natural numbers are a subset of real numbers ... at least that would be the easiest way to get around the errors incurred by a user inputting doubles or any other floating point type.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO : In order to meet your assignment you need to first read the number as a string
then you may want to check if the number is a natural number i.e. check if there is a '.' in the string, if not then do what you did before otherwise give an error message.